# How to traverse json structure for any numerical Id

Tags: javascript, json

```
    {
      "123": {
        "question": "Alert Me When Redmi 3S Available jan-18th 12 noon on FLIPKART.",
        "answer": [
          "Battery is removable or non-removable?",
          "NON-REMOVABLE ..... but powerful battery..."
        ]
      },
      "124": {
        "question": "Can we use Jio SIM in this phone?",
        "answer": [
          "Yeah of course\n",
          "I don't think so it supports Jio sim card"
        ]
      },
      "125": {
        "question": "Is MI note 4 supports 4G?",
        "answer": [
          "Yeah of course\n",
          "I don't think so it supports Jio sim card"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this eample:

```
var jsonVar = /* Your JSON */;
for (id in jsonVar) {
    console.log(jsonVarp[id]);
}
```